# eprecated: The behavior of unparenthesized expressions containing both '.' a

Tags: php, html, wordpress, deprecated

I created my website years ago using a theme that is not supported anymore.  Today this error along with a few others showed up.  I'm not sure how to resolve it.  I am not tech savvy (PS:  I don't use the reservation part of the site anymore as it's being outsourced)

> **Deprecated**: The behavior of unparenthesized expressions
> containing both '.' and '+'/'-' will change in PHP 8: '+'/'-' will
> take a higher precedence in
> /home/f0602855/domains/mysite.com/public_html/wp-content/themes/welcome_inn-parent/framework/extensions/reservationform/config/utils.php
> on line 4

```
 $id = str_split(''.RESERVATION_START_NUMBER + $id.'');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not really sure what you would like to achieve by this line of code, but to avoid "deprecated" message you can just use parenthesis to correctly keep order of expressions (adding a number to a number and concatenate strings) just like this:

```php
$id = str_split('' . (RESERVATION_START_NUMBER + $id) . '');
```